# Why is JPCT-AE AGL font class only working on Android emulator?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator, hardware, jpct

I am currently using the JPCT-AE framework to build a 3D game for android. Because it does not have a class for displaying Fonts yet, it has created what is called an AGLFont class for displaying text on the android screen. Here is the link to the Forum with this class.

http://www.jpct.net/forum2/index.php/topic,1563.0.html

This class works great on the Android emulator, but it seems to not display text and not cause the game to break when it is used on the android phone. We have tried using this class on two Android phones [Droid X & Nexus S] with no success.

Does anyone know how to configure this code to work a physical phone or why their might be a difference between the emulator and actual phone?